# Markov's Inequality for Negative Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given that $Y$ follows Negative Binomial distribution (counts y successes before $k$th failure), using Markov's inequality show that for any $q \in[p,1]$, there exists constant $C$, such that $\mathbb{P}(Y>x)\leq Cq^x$.

$E(Y)=\frac{kp}{1-p}$ and from Markov's inequality:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(Y>x)\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(Y)}{x}=\frac{kp}{(1-p)x}
\end{equation}

HOW to relate $Cq^x$ and $\frac{kp}{(1-p)x}\qquad$?

Comment: The RHS is increasing in $q$, so it suffices to find a $C$ that does it for $q=p$, or not?

Comment: And something else: p is the probability of success or failure?

Comment: @Stefanos $p$ is probability of success, that is $Y$ counts number of successes before $r$th failure, thus \begin{equation} \mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\begin{pmatrix} y+r-1\\ y \end{pmatrix}p^y(1-p)^r\end{equation}

Comment: @Stefanos inconsistency - in above equation should be $k$ instead of $r$, that is $k$ failures

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. I still do not see an answer thouhg

Comment: @Stefanos are you considering Markov's Inequality also?

Comment: Ok firstly, as I said in my first comment, you do not need to consider q>p since RHS is increasing in q. So you can write $p^x$ on the RHS (p is the lower limit of the given interval for q). Do you agree? Secondly, I do not think this is Markov...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18377/discussion-between-stefanos-and-ruth90).

Comment: @Stefanos Yes I absolutely agree that we can change $q^p$ to $p^x$

Comment: @Stefanos please tell me what do you think.
Generalised Markov's Inequality:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(|Y|>x)=\frac{\mathbb{E}f(Y)}{f(x)}
\end{equation}
Since Y is non-negative r.v. we can remove modulus. Moreover, if we take $f(x)=p^x$, then $\mathbb{E}(p^Y)=\Bigg(\frac{1-p}{1-p^2}\Bigg)^r=(1-p)^{-r}$ since the expectation is generating function r.v. $Y$

Comment: @Stefanos Then $\mathbb{P}(Y>x) \leq (1-p)^{-r}p^{-x}=(1-p)^{-r}p^{-2x}p^x$ and hence $C=(1-p)^{-r}p^{-2x}$

Comment: @Stefanos i think the problem with this is that $C$ is not a constant. What do you think?

Comment: @Stefanos please note the typo - general. Markov Ineq. should be $\leq$

Comment: Yes, C is not a constant and that is a problem

Comment: It also works for f(x)=(1/p)^x. Then $E[(1/p)^Y]=(1-1/p)^-r and then you have it. Do you agree?

Comment: @Stefanos well if we take $f(x)=p^{-x)$ then probability generating function
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(p^{-Y})=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}Bp^{-y}p^y(1-p)^r\end{equation}
where $B$ is appropriate binomial coefficient. Thus in this case $p$ term will disapear and thus series will not converge. Do you agree? Thus I assume we cannot substitute $p$ and $q$ in initial bounds. If we keep $q$ we will get probability generating function $(1-\frac{p}{q})^{-r}$ which will make $C$ constant. Agree?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}((\frac{1}{p})^Y)=\Bigg(\frac{1-p}{1-\frac{1}{p}p}\Bigg)$ actually

Comment: @Stefanos But then it is said that $q\in[p,1]$. So the expectation above would give some incosistency since if $q=p$ we divide by $0$ . do you agree?

Comment: @Stefanos so I think if we set $f(x)=q^{-x}$ then we have $C=\mathbb{E}(q^{-Y})$. Since the question asks to show that there exists a constant C such that $\mathbb{P}(Y>x)\leq Cq^x$ we are done. What do you think??

Comment: I think we are done... you did it ok, I can't think of something else

Answer (score 1):

Consider a non-negative and increasing function $f$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(f(Y)) &=\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}f(y)\mathbb{P}(Y=y)\\
&= \sum_{y=0}^{x}f(y)\mathbb{P}(Y=y) +\sum_{y=x+1}^{\infty}f(y)\mathbb{P}(Y=y)\\
&\geq \sum_{y=x+1}^{\infty}f(y)\mathbb{P}(Y=y)\\
&\geq f(x)\sum_{y=x+1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(Y=y)\\
&= f(x)\mathbb{P}(Y>x)\\
&\implies \mathbb{P}(Y>x) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(f(Y))}{f(x)}.
\end{align}
Now let $f(x)=q^{-x}$, then
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(Y>x) \leq \mathbb{E}(q^{-Y})q^x.
\end{equation}
Hence, $C=\mathbb{E}(q^{-Y})$. Moreover, if we set $\alpha=\frac{1}{q}$ we have  $C=\mathbb{E}(\alpha^Y)$ and 
\begin{align}
C=\Bigg(\frac{1-p}{1-\frac{p}{q}}\Bigg)^r
\end{align}

Comment: the last equation follows from PGF of the Negative Binomial distribution.